# How to use a class without including its file?

Tags: php, class

I have seen in many frameworks that you can use methods of an extended class without including the file. E.g.

```
Class MyController extends Controller {
```

When I do the same without a framework and try to call the method, I'll get:

> Fatal error: Class 'Helper' not found in ...

Why am I not able to use that class without including its file? And why does that work for frameworks?

Can I get rid of the including part if I used namespaces?

Comment: [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) - [Examples](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader-examples.md)

Comment: This way or that You can not use a class without proper reference to it. For reference you can include main file or include autoloader

Comment: @PaulCrovella __autoload is being phased out.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php should be used instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most frameworks, libraries, etc use an [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) to automagically load a class that's requested but not in memory.

The preferred practice these days is to have a directory/file structure that mirrors your namespaces, so the class `\Foo\Bar\Baz` will be stored in a directory (relative to your base path) `/Foo/Bar/Baz.php`.  You can implement a very simple autoloader that can handle this:

```
// Assume that BASE_DIR is a constant that is set somewhere

spl_autoload_register (function ($class) {
    $class = str_replace ("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);
    if (!is_file (BASE_DIR . $class)) {
        throw new \LogicException ("Class $class not found");
    }
    require (BASE_DIR . $class);
});
```

Now when you try to create a new \Foo\Bar\Baz without explicitly requiring it yourself the autoloader will be automatically invoked and try to require it for you.  If \Foo\Bar\Baz also has dependencies that aren't explicitly required then the autoloader will attempt to load them too.

The above example is rather ad-hoc and is more for demonstration purposes than something intended to be used in production but hopefully it gets the idea across.  These days a lot of applications rely on [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to handle autoloading for them, as it is capable of generating an autoloader file that will handle all this stuff for you.  All you have to do is include/require the Composer autoloader and everything else will be taken care of.

Comment: The joke is I need to use the Autoloader-class to start autoloading. But class not found etc. There is no clean answer here.

Answer (score -2):

Because Framework implements Class load with a code like this

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$url = rtrim($url, '/');
$url = explode('/', $url);
require 'controllers/'.$url[0].'.php';
$controller = new $url[0];
```

So when you call http://somesite.com/help/ it will include file controller/help.php with class Help in it

```
<?php
   class Help {
   public function __construct() {
   echo "You are in HELP";
   }
}
?>
```

**Note: It is just an example for novices!!!**, actually they uses http://php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: No, frameworks typically use an autoloader, not hacks like this.  It wouldn't be able to cope with the case where one class needs another class that hasn't been loaded yet.  Also, allowing visitors to load arbitary PHP code via a variable in $_GET is completely unsafe.  I can simply put ?url=url%3D..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2F..%2Fetc%2Fpasswd and dump all your passwords out

Comment: I agreed, but this is just an example for novices